# Testing Spring @MVC annotations

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I ran into a problem the other day where a @Valid annotation was accidentally removed from a controller class.  Unfortunately, it didn't break any of our tests.  None of our unit tests actually exercise the Spring `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` pathway.  We just test our controller classes directly.

How can I write a unit or integration test that will correctly fail if my @MVC annotations are wrong?  Is there a way I can ask Spring to find and exercise the relevant controller with a MockHttpServlet or something?

Comment: You wouldn't unit test an annotation, would you? Seems to be an integration test concern to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In upcoming spring 3.2 (SNAPSHOT available) or with spring-test-mvc (https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc) you can do it like this:

first we emulate Validation as we do not want to test the validator, just want to know if validation is called.

```
public class LocalValidatorFactoryBeanMock extends LocalValidatorFactoryBean
{
    private boolean fakeErrors;

    public void fakeErrors ( )
    {
        this.fakeErrors = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports ( Class<?> clazz )
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate ( Object target, Errors errors, Object... validationHints )
    {
        if (fakeErrors)
        {
            errors.reject("error");
        }
    }
}
```

this is our test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration
public class RegisterControllerTest
{
 @Autowired
 private WebApplicationContext  wac;
 private MockMvc mockMvc;

     @Autowired
     @InjectMocks
     private RegisterController registerController;

     @Autowired
     private LocalValidatorFactoryBeanMock  validator;

  @Before
  public void setup ( )
  {
     this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
     // if you want to inject mocks into your controller
             MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

    @Test
    public void testPostValidationError ( ) throws Exception
    {
        validator.fakeErrors();
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder post = post("/info/register");
        post.param("name", "Bob");
        ResultActions result = getMockMvc().perform(post);
            // no redirect as we have errors
        result.andExpect(view().name("info/register"));
    }

    @Configuration
    @Import(DispatcherServletConfig.class)
    static class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
    {
        @Override
        public Validator getValidator ( )
        {
            return new LocalValidatorFactoryBeanMock();
        }

        @Bean
        RegisterController registerController ( )
        {
            return new RegisterController();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I write integration tests for this kind of thing.  Say you have a bean with validation annotations:

```
public class MyForm {
    @NotNull
    private Long myNumber;

    ...
}
```

and a controller that handles the submission

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/simple-form")
public class MyController {
    private final static String FORM_VIEW = null;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processFormSubmission(@Valid MyForm myForm,
            BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return FORM_VIEW;
        }
        // process the form
        return "success-view";
    }
}
```

and you want to test that the @Valid and @NotNull annotations are wired correctly:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"file:web/WEB-INF/application-context.xml",
    "file:web/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml"})
public class MyControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Inject
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private MockHttpServletRequest request;
    private MockHttpServletResponse response;
    private HandlerAdapter handlerAdapter;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        this.response = new MockHttpServletResponse();

        this.handlerAdapter = applicationContext.getBean(HandlerAdapter.class);
    }

    ModelAndView handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        final HandlerMapping handlerMapping = applicationContext.getBean(HandlerMapping.class);
        final HandlerExecutionChain handler = handlerMapping.getHandler(request);
        assertNotNull("No handler found for request, check you request mapping", handler);

        final Object controller = handler.getHandler();
        // if you want to override any injected attributes do it here

        final HandlerInterceptor[] interceptors =
            handlerMapping.getHandler(request).getInterceptors();
        for (HandlerInterceptor interceptor : interceptors) {
            final boolean carryOn = interceptor.preHandle(request, response, controller);
            if (!carryOn) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        final ModelAndView mav = handlerAdapter.handle(request, response, controller);
        return mav;
    }

    @Test
    public void testProcessFormSubmission() throws Exception {
        request.setMethod("POST");
        request.setRequestURI("/simple-form");
        request.setParameter("myNumber", "");

        final ModelAndView mav = handle(request, response);
        // test we're returned back to the form
        assertViewName(mav, "simple-form");
        // make assertions on the errors
        final BindingResult errors = assertAndReturnModelAttributeOfType(mav, 
                "org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.myForm", 
                BindingResult.class);
        assertEquals(1, errors.getErrorCount());
        assertEquals("", errors.getFieldValue("myNumber"));        
    }
```

See my blog post on [integration testing Spring's MVC annotations](http://www.scarba05.co.uk/blog/2010/07/more-on-integration-testing-of-spring%E2%80%99s-mvc-annotation-mapppings-for-controllers/)

Comment: This is friggin' awesome.  This is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Sure. There's no reason why your test can't instantiate its own `DispatcherServlet`, inject it with the various items which it would have in a container (e.g. `ServletContext`), including the location of the context definition file.

Spring comes with a variety of servlet-related `MockXYZ` classes for this purpose, including `MockServletContext`, `MockHttpServletRequest` and `MockHttpServletResponse`. They're not really "mock" objects in the usual sense, they're more like dumb stubs, but they do the job.

The servlet's test context would have the usual MVC-related beans, plus your beans to test. Once the servlet is initialized, create the mock requests and responses, and feed them into the servet's `service()` method. If request gets routed correctly, you can check the results as written to the mock response.