# Spring MVC testing mapping with RedirectAttribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mockito

My problem is similar these:

- [Testing Spring MVC annotation mapppings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861089/testing-spring-mvc-annotation-mapppings)
- [Testing Spring @MVC annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314377/testing-spring-mvc-annotations)

BUT

Given a controller method signature:

```
public String setupForm(
    @ModelAttribute("notification") Notification n, RedirectAttributes redirect)
```

And given a Test (using Mockito):

```
@Mock
private AddNotificationController handler;
@Test
public void get() throws Exception{
    request.setRequestURI("/addNotification/save.do");
    request.setMethod("GET");
    adapter.handle(request, response, handler);
    verify(handler,times(1)).setupForm(any(Notification.class), any(RedirectAttributes.class));
  }
```

And when executing I got exception:

```
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException: 
Failed to invoke handler method [public java.lang.String ep.rdp.web.AddNotificationController.setupForm(a.b.c.Notification,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)]; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Argument [RedirectAttributes] is of type Model or Map but is not assignable from the actual model. 
You may need to switch newer MVC infrastructure classes to use this argument.
```

Actually I know the problem and know how to resolve by setting up spring properly but not in unit test.

So the question: what else I have to setup in mocks to make it working?

Additional info

Base setting up mocks:

```
  @Before
  public void setup() {
//    adapter = new AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter();
    adapter = new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
    request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    /*
     * needed for AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter when resolving controlle level mapping
     */
    request.setAttribute(HandlerMapping.INTROSPECT_TYPE_LEVEL_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
    response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
  }
```

In real

- when using AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter i have this symptom.
- when I use RequestMappingHandlerAdapter I got:

  java.lang.ClassCastException: ep.rdp.web.CacheController$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$d8aab2c0 cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod
      at     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something about your question but I don't understand why you're creating a mock of your controller to test it... I guess that spring try do read annotations on your class controller with reflection but i can not use reflection on your mock properly.

I think it's not the correct way to test your mapping. Spring provide this module to unit test your controller and everything is provided. So you shouldn't create any mock here. Maybe a @Spy (a spy apply on real object) if you want to mock a method on your real object.

What you are trying to do is to create something like this :

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(new AddNotificationController())
            .build();
}

// and your test
@Test
public void testYourMethodName() {
    this.mockMvc.perform(MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.get("/addNotification/save.do"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.handler().method("yourMethodName"))
            .abdExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.redirectedUrl("yourUrl"));
}
```

As you can see, you don't use any mock object provided by mockito but i still check the fact that the request is handle by the method "yourMethodName". If you need some mock, it should be inside your class AddNotificationController. So, use @InjectMock on this class and create the @Mock object used inside your controller juste here. I think, that this should probably work fine :

```
@Mock
public SomeService service;

@InjectMocks
public AddNotificationController controller = new AddNotificationController();

@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(this.controller)
            .build();
}
```

PS : sorry for my english.